# IIS / ASP.NET MVC gives error when adding query strings to URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, query-string

We run an ASP.NET MVC website (let's say www.domain.com), on IIS.
When adding a random query-string to the URL, let's say www.domain.com?abcdefg, the code yields an error page and changes the URL into something like www.domain.com/nl/nl?abcdefg
I am asking this, because when people share our site www.domain.com on Facebook or elsewhere, it goes wrong. Although Facebook successfully fetches the OpenGraph meta data (such as page title, opengraph image, etcetera) and displays a neat 'snippet (preview)', if you click on the snippet you're being redirected to an error page generated by code.
Does anyone know how to prevend this?

(as background info: the normal URLs are built up like www.domain.com/nl/..... and they work fine)

Comment: Do you have a page that will accept that route, with query string parameters?

Comment: What error are you seeing ?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application - The resource cannot be found.

Comment: Looks like a routing error. Can you paste your routing configuration?

Comment: Sounds like 404 error coming from URL routing configuration. Please show your `RouteConfig` and controller action code, also mention if you're using attribute routing.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto and others:

`namespace MyProject.Web {

    public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
      
      routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}`